# Add Custom headers in Istio Virtual service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using Istio 1.10.0 with minikube. Kubernetes server version is 1.19.8.

How to add multiple headers in http request? Is it possible to place dynamic values like `request.headers["Host"]`?

```
X-Forwarded-Host $host;    
X-Forwarded-Port 9090;
X-Forwarded-Proto http;
```

Below sample is working fine for adding response header.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install, pre-upgrade
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-22T13:01:36Z"
  generation: 8
  name: direct-vs
  namespace: cvrm
  resourceVersion: "72069"
  selfLink: /apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/cvrm/virtualservices/cvrm-direct-vs
  uid: d398a13e-fd81-4ada-8e36-617287cae1bc
spec:
  gateways:
  - gateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /console
    route:
    - destination:
        host: console-bs.cvrm.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8087
      headers:
        response:
          add:
            Custom-Header: test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add headers to requests the same way you did with response.

```yaml
...
headers:
  request:
    add:
      foo: bar
...
```

If you want to add multiple headers added you can try

```yaml
...
headers:
  request:
    add:
      foo: foo
      bar: bar
...
```

It's not possible to add dynamic values in Istio manifests.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch values from request headers like referrer , Host and set it in virtual service using some expression language ex: request.headers["Host"]?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to set X-Forwarded-Host and X-Forwarded-Port in headers using istio virtual service.

Comment: Ok, but why? Maybe there is an alternative, but it depends on your exact usecase.

Comment: You could also write an EnvoyFilter that extracts that information and adds the headers to your request. Not sure if information is available there though.